# Why does this mkdir command using a variable value not work?

Tags: bash

I want to create a directory given in a variable value. First let's ensure the directory can be created via the simplest command:

```
$ mkdir ~/opt
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-193 ~]$ ls ~/opt
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-193 ~]$ ls -l ~/opt
total 0
```

What is the syntax for using a variable in place of the hard-coded path? Here is what has been tried:

```
$ BDIR="~/opt"
$ mkdir $BDIR
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘~/opt’: No such file or directory
```

Also:

```
$ mkdir "$BDIR"
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘~/opt’: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5):

Normally what you're doing would work. It's the "~" character that's tricking you here.

You cannot use "~" outside a bash prompt because it's a [shell expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html).

You need to explicitly use the `$HOME` variable:

```
BDIR="$HOME/opt"
```

Or you can omit the quote signs, this way the BDIR assignment will be to the expanded path and it will work:

```
BDIR=~/opt
```

(if needed, you can escape spaces with slashes - `BDIR=~/path\ with\ spaces` ).

Or, as @Attie suggested, keep the tilde outside the quotes:

```
BDIR=~"/opt"
```

Comment: Thx - will award in a few..

Comment: `~"/opt"` would also work... useful if spaces are an issue

Comment: It's worth noting that `no such file or directory` refers to the directory literally named `~` in the OP's current working directory. If it existed, the troublesome command would create `opt` directory *there*.

Comment: @Attie For reasons I'm not clear on, the `/` sometimes also needs to be unquoted. That is, `~"/opt"` *might* work, but `~/"opt"` *will* work.

Comment: Interesting, thanks @GordonDavisson ... I've not noticed that as an issue before, but I'll bear it in mind.